# Why Python only uses 30-bit from every 32-bit unsigned integers instead of using up all 32 bits?

Tags: python, integer, cpython

I found that Python only use 30-bit in every 32-bit unsigned integer from arrays. If all 32 bits are used it can represent a larger integer, but Python chooses to leave two bits remained. Why does Python not use all bits of the integer? What's the rationale behind this? And how are the remaining 2 bits used?

[quote](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/865e4b4f630e2ae91e61239258abb58b488f1d65/Include/longintrepr.h#L9)

> There are two different
> sets of parameters: one set for 30-bit digits, stored in an unsigned 32-bit
> integer type, and one set for 15-bit digits with each digit stored in an
> unsigned short.

Comment: Read on. Later in the code you see the comment "the marshal code currently expects that PyLong_SHIFT is a multiple of 15". That might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Python **array** of 32-bit unsigned integers **use of course all 32-bits for each element**, but if you extract one element by indexing then it is converted to the universal Python arbitrary precision signed integer. You probably **measured a size of an extracted element**.

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(array('L', [2**32 - 1])) - sys.getsizeof(array('L', [0]))
0
>>> # your surprise
>>> sys.getsizeof(array('L', [2**32 - 1])[0]) - sys.getsizeof(array('L', [0])[0])
4
```

Python arbitrary precision integer uses one bit as a continuation mark that the number continues in the next 32-bit word and only 30 bits for digits. That is because ty

```py
>>> sys.getsizeof(2**30 - 1) - sys.getsizeof(0)
0
>>> sys.getsizeof(2**30) - sys.getsizeof(0)
4
>>> sys.getsizeof(2**60) - sys.getsizeof(0)
8
```

These examples are for any Python 3.x on a 64-bit or 32-bit system.
(In MicroPython on a 16-bit system it would be stored by 15 + 1.)